# Phone number issue Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem with my the wordpress website, when i preview it on my mobile it shows different phone number i used last year, but i changed it and still show my old one. On desktop computer is everything alright, shows all changes normally, but with mobile device keeps the old phone number. This is a link of the website, you can check it on both devices. I tried even friend's phone and its still same, shows the old one.

[link to the website](http://scopedigit.com.au)

Its the header one, footer is alright, just top phone number doesn't want to change.

PS: needs to show phone number with last 3 digits 488, currently showing 636

Thanks for any help,

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into style.css file. in your theme

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.mkdf-top-bar {
    display: block !important;
}

#text-19 {
    display: none !important;
}
}
```

or if you want to change only phone number. check widgets into admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change the phone number in a section which was shown in mobile. Its in line **347** of your source code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you've helped.Cheers